# Finding difference between specific rows by group

Tags: r, dataframe, rows

Within a group, I want to find the difference between that row and the first time that user appeared in the data. For example, I need to create the `diff` variable below. Users have different number of rows each as in the following data:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L), 
    money = c(9L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 10L), occurence = c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L), diff = c(NA, 3L, 4L, 
    6L, NA, 2L, 3L, NA, NA, 8L)), .Names = c("ID", "money", "occurence", 
"diff"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

   ID money occurence diff
1   1     9         1   NA
2   1    12         2    3
3   1    13         3    4
4   1    15         4    6
5   2     5         1   NA
6   2     7         2    2
7   2     8         3    3
8   3     5         1   NA
9   4     2         1   NA
10  4    10         2    8
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ave()`.  We just remove the first value per group and replace it with `NA`, and subtract the first value from the rest of the values.

```
with(df, ave(money, ID, FUN = function(x) c(NA, x[-1] - x[1])))
# [1] NA  3  4  6 NA  2  3 NA NA  8
```

Answer (score 1):

A [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) solution, which uses the `first` function to get the first value and calculate the difference.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(diff = money - first(money)) %>%
  mutate(diff = replace(diff, diff == 0, NA)) %>%
  ungroup()
df2
# # A tibble: 10 x 4
#       ID money occurence  diff
#    <int> <int>     <int> <int>
#  1     1     9         1    NA
#  2     1    12         2     3
#  3     1    13         3     4
#  4     1    15         4     6
#  5     2     5         1    NA
#  6     2     7         2     2
#  7     2     8         3     3
#  8     3     5         1    NA
#  9     4     2         1    NA
# 10     4    10         2     8
```

#### Update

Here is a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) solution provided by Sotos. Notice that no need to replace 0 with `NA`.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, money := money - first(money), by = ID][]
#     ID money occurence diff
#  1:  1     0         1   NA
#  2:  1     3         2    3
#  3:  1     4         3    4
#  4:  1     6         4    6
#  5:  2     0         1   NA
#  6:  2     2         2    2
#  7:  2     3         3    3
#  8:  3     0         1   NA
#  9:  4     0         1   NA
# 10:  4     8         2    8
```

**DATA**

```
dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L), 
    money = c(9L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 10L), occurence = c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L)), .Names = c("ID", "money", 
"occurence"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: this also works: `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(diff2 = money - money[1])` but I hesitate to post it as a real answer...I am not sure if this fails in certain cases. I have noticed that it works but have not seen many examples of this syntax.

Comment: FYI, you don't need two mutates. `... %>% mutate(diff = money - first(money), diff = replace(diff, diff == 0, NA))` works just fine. Also `data.table` has a function `first` which has NA as default, i.e. `setDT(df)[, money := money - first(money), by = ID]`. You can add this in your answer as well if you like.

Comment: @MattL. Thanks for your comment. I think your solution works.

Comment: @Sotos Thanks for your comment. I will update my post including you suggestions and the `data.table` solution.